# Re-scaled axis in Python plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axis, scaling

In the code below as I grow up the value of "Ns" (say, "Ns=1000") more the cossine function appears smooth, in the [-pi,pi] interval. My intention is to re-scale the k-axis dividing it by a factor "pi", such that the graph becomes defined in the [-1,1] interval. However, when I do that trough, say

```
k2=[]
    for i in k:
    k2.append(i/pi)
```

and plot (k2,en(k2) instead of (k,en(k), the plotted graph assumes more a parabola form than the correct cossine one. I will apreciate any help.

The main code is:

```
def en(k):
return -2*cos(k) 

k=[]
e=[]

Ns=input('Ns: ')

n=[0]
for i in range(0,Ns/2+1):
    if i==0:
        continue
    else:
        n.append(i)
        n.append(-i)

if len(n)>Ns:  
    del n[0]

for i in n:
k.append(2*pi*i/Ns)

k.sort()

plt.plot(k,en(k),'b-')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is `cos(x*pi)` instead of `cos(x/pi)`. That way you get a function of similar shape that is [-1,1]-periodic. So simply redefine

```
def en(k):
    return -2*cos(pi*k)
```

Your expression to transform `k` into `k2` can be more simple written as `k2 = [i*pi for i in k]`. This is called a "list comprehension" and your code would look much nicer with some of them (maybe reduced to 4-5 lines).